# How to prove a set of sequences is compact?

Tags: sequences-and-series, compactness

Can anyone give me some clues on how to solve this problem? I think I need to construct a sequence of sequences and show the convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a): You can look at the following sequence:
\begin{equation}
(1,0,0,\ldots)\\
(0,1,0,\ldots)\\
(0,0,1,\ldots)\\
\vdots
\end{equation}

For (b): First note that for every $\epsilon>0$ and any two elements $y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots)$ and $z=(z_1,z_2,\ldots)$ we have $\sum_{n=N+1}^{+\infty}|y_n-z_n|<\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $N$.

Now if you have sequence $x^1,x^2,\ldots$ in $C$ you can observe that 
\begin{equation}
x^n_j\in \left[-\frac{1}{2^j},\frac{1}{2^j}\right]\ n\in\mathbb N,j\in\mathbb N.
\end{equation}
Thus every sequence $\{x^n_j\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ has convergent subsequence.

You can couple this with what we noted at the begining.

For (c): Look at the following sequence:
\begin{equation}
(1,0,0,0\ldots)\\
(1,1/2,0,0,\ldots)\\
(1,1/2,1/3,0\ldots)\\
\vdots
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks so much! So next I need to prove that any subsequence of this sequence does not converge to any elements of B?

Comment: You try to see what is the distance between any two sequences that was provided in this answer. Then see if for ANY epsilon you can find a N such that all the sequences after the Nth one lies in the epsilon ball of L(L is the supposed limit). You will immediately realize why such an L cannot exist.

Comment: Oh! I see! Thanks so much. It's really helpful.

Comment: @JiuLian You can see that distance between any two members of sequence is equal to 2. Thus, no subsequence is Cauchy. Thus, no subsequence is convergent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very straightforward.

Comment: Hi, I added a question part (c). Could you please help me to look at it?

Answer (score 0):

For part a I want to point out an important result from Functional Analysis.

> The closed unit ball in a normed linear space is compact iff it is finite dimensional vector space. (This is a standard result and I will allow you to find the solution yourself).

Now in a normed linear space (which is a metric space) sequential compactness and compactness are the same. Can you see why this solves part a?

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot fully understand. I haven't approach to any material about the dimensional vector space. Could you please give me some clues on how to prove that use the sequential compactness definition?

Comment: Actually the other answer already posted is the "from definition" answer. I just provided a general setup to show why it actually is true.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm working on the other answer!

Comment: Hi, I've solved the first two parts. I added the third part (c). Could you please help me to have a look at it?